# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined" in E2E test

Tags: typescript, websocket, jestjs, nestjs

I would like to test my WebSocket, but I have the problem that my test runs into an error and the test process just keeps running and does not end. (error see image).

[image]

The code that already leads to an error:

```
describe("Event Gateway (E2E)", () => {
    let app: INestApplication;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        app = await globalBeforeAll([GatewayModule]);
    });

    afterAll(async () => {
        await app.close();
    });

    describe("Connection to WebSocket", () => {
        it("should be successfully", () => {
            // here should come some expectations ...
        });
    });
});
```

The globalBeforeAll is just a helper method to make the tests a bit more readable. This contains the override of the guards and additionally the  **useWebSocketAdapter(new RedisIoAdapter(application))**

The RedisIoAdapter will later become its own adapter, which I can then use to make PubSub via Redis. For test purposes, it currently looks quite basic like this:

```
import { ServerOptions } from "socket.io";
import { IoAdapter } from "@nestjs/platform-socket.io";

export class RedisIoAdapter extends IoAdapter {
    createIOServer(port: number, options?: ServerOptions): any {
        return super.createIOServer(port, options);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check if and how often the `beforeAll()` and `afterAll()` hooks are called respectively? If `app` is still undefined, `beforeAll()` probably never ran. On the other hand, if it's never opened, you don't _need_ to close it per sé. You could add `if(app) await app.close()` for something quick and dirty.

Comment: I think you need to show us the implementation of `globalBeforeAll`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the problem was in the *globalBeforeAll*. Previously, the method looked like this:

```
export async function globalBeforeAll(additionalModules: Array<{ new (): any }>): Promise<INestApplication> {
    const app = await Test.createTestingModule(ModuleMetadataBuilder.build(additionalModules, true))
        .overrideGuard(JwtAuthGuard)
        .useClass(OverridesAuthGuard)
        .overrideGuard(RolesAuthGuard)
        .useClass(OverridesRolesGuard)
        .compile()
        .then((application) => application
            .createNestApplication()
            .useWebSocketAdapter(new RedisIoAdapter(app))
            .init(),
        );

    app.enableShutdownHooks();
    Authorizer.init(app);

    return app;
}
```

I have had to change it as follows and it works now:

```
export async function globalBeforeAll(additionalModules: Array<{ new (): any }>): Promise<INestApplication> {
    const app = await Test.createTestingModule(ModuleMetadataBuilder.build(additionalModules, true))
        .overrideGuard(JwtAuthGuard)
        .useClass(OverridesAuthGuard)
        .overrideGuard(RolesAuthGuard)
        .useClass(OverridesRolesGuard)
        .compile()
        .then((application) => application.createNestApplication());

    app.useWebSocketAdapter(new RedisIoAdapter(app));
    app.enableShutdownHooks();
    Authorizer.init(app);

    return app.init();
}
```